# How to set arbitrary number of values for variables in Banjo

Tags: java, machine-learning, bayesian-networks, discretization

I'm using Banjo (BAyesian Network inference with Java Objects) to analyze a set of data. I want each variable to take a range of more than 7 values (Banjo put this limit in the amount of values a variable can take), without using Banjo discretization policy (ix, qx). Is there any way to do it modifying only the settings file, or do I have to modify the code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be found in the banjo user guide: This integer should be at least 1, and no larger than the maximum number of states permitted for any discrete variable in Banjo (which is 5 by default) but can be adjusted to a larger value in BANJO.java.